# How to set file provider for images stored in app data folder

Tags: java, android, android-fileprovider, android-camerax

I have been working on `CameraX` API and storing captured image on `Internal storage` App data folder with path say `storage/emulated/0/Android/data/packageName/Files/IMG_25052021_171806.jpg`

Now i want to get content URI for this saved image. For this i have been using `provider` in `Manifest`.

```
<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.abc.xyz.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepath" />
    </provider>
```

with `File path` as

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<files-path name="my_images" path="/" />
```

When i am calling `FileProvider.getUriForFile(ImageCrop.this,"com.abc.xyz.fileprovider", pictureFile);` it returning me `Illegal Argument Exception`

Please suggest !!!

Comment: `<files-path` That is the wrong path. If you googel just FileProvider you come to the android developer page for FileProvider and there you can find all.

Comment: @blackapps thanks for sharing. It helps me lot. Issue resolved

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using `getExternalFilesDir()` for the filesystem location. If so, use `<external-files-path>`, not `<files-path>`, in your metadata XML resource. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider#SpecifyFiles) for more.